# Is it possible to modify docker run option without removing and recreating the container?

Tags: docker

I'm working with docker containers and I have a question related to the "run" command: when I use it with some options (like -p or -e) can I change these options without removing the container and re-launching the entire command? I have seen that the "start" command does not accept other options so I don't see another way for doing it.

Comment: I don't get your point! Do you have some code which does not behave as expected? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: For example adding a port or volume mapping. Another example: if I was wrong running the first command I need three other command (stop, rm and run again with the correct options) in order to fix my error. I was wandering if there is a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. (My comments are based on Docker v1.8.3).

The options currently available in "docker exec" or "docker restart" commands are quite limited and do not allow such a thing.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping that this could be possible. Thanks.